# Encoding issue with PHPMailer 5.2.1

Tags: utf-8, phpmailer

I am trying to include words containing a diaresis (particularly "ë" in messages through PHPMailer, but am getting "ÃÂ«" in the emails.

I have included the following right after instantiating my class:

```
$mail->Encoding= 'base64';  
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

The character encoding appears correct when I preview it in a browser:
[image: preview of message contents in Chrome]

But when I view it in gmail, I get junk:
[image: image of message contents in Gmail/Chrome]

I have also tried running the content of the message through iconv, mb_convert_encoding, and even str_replace, all to no avail.

What can I do to make sure that characters like this show up correctly in emails sent via PHPMailer?

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth are you using such an ancient (from 2012!), buggy & vulnerable version of PHPMailer? [Update now](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Also your images are broken.

Aside from that, `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';` should be all you need, though you do also need to be sure that you are actually feeding UTF-8 content into it, so check your sources. You don't need to set the encoding at all - in fact you're more likely to get marked as spam if you base64-encode message bodies.